# Move a java class file from one branch in git to another branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I have this java class **flie.java** which I commited and pushed with other java files in **branch A**. I want to move just the file.java from **branch A to branch B** without moving the other files that are pushed in branch A. I tried to do it from eclipse but It wasn't possible. I tried from git by following these steps: [moving a file in git](https://help.github.com/articles/moving-a-file-to-a-new-location/) but there wasn't the option to move it to an existing branch. I know I can copy the file and paste it to branch B in eclipse, but that is not the purpose!
Is there any git command that I can possibly use to move that file?

Comment: Why you don't want to copy paste it? `git` doesn't support of moving files between branches. In fact you can't modify history in `git`.

Comment: @talex: You *can* modify history in Git, and rather easily (at least compared to Subversion and the like).  See `git commit --amend`, `git rebase`, `git reset --hard`, and `git push --force`, among other commands.

Comment: @jwodder - Well, that depends on how you look at it.  You can modify the perceived history of a ref - at a cost

Comment: I forgot about git push --force, but it is disabled on most servers anyway. Other commands change local repo only.

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout commitOrBranch -- path/to/file
```

> So git checkout branchB -- path/file.java this with just checkout the branch with the file be moved then? – Marco

The file will be added to the current branch. Git will not raise a *conflict* when both branches will be merged.

But it may raise a *conflict* if you delete the file in the original branch before the merge.

---

> If either side modifies the file further (not merely if the original branch deletes it) a conflict will almost certainly be raised. – Mark Adelsberger

The conflict is raised only if the file is change on *both* branches (before merge). This is exactly the advantage of "copying" the file via `git` instead of doing it via file system.

Comment: Note that this doesn't move file, but simply copy it to disk. You need to `add`, `commit` and `push` it after `checkout`.

Comment: So git checkout branchB -- path/file.java this with just checkout the branch with the file be moved then?

Comment: If either side modifies the file further (not merely if the original branch deletes it) a conflict will almost certainly be raised.

Comment: @talex It didn't work. I checked out branch A and from there I used the git add to branch B and it didn't add the file to branch B

Comment: @talex I tried it again and I saw that I did a mistake earlier now I used the checkout on the branch that I want the file to be so: git checkout branch a file.java then I got the file on branch B. The file is now added into branch B. Thank you